# Should I use "simple past" or "past simple" when talking about tense grammar?

Tags: reference

It seems that [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_past) accepts both "simple past" and "past simple"

> The simple past, past simple or past indefinite, sometimes called the preterite, is the basic form of the past tense in Modern English.

which one is being used in some widely recognized references such as Cambridge English?

Comment: Scholarly grammar has preterite. The other past tense is the perfect.

Comment: @BillJ I guess you prefer "past tense", and I am aware that preterite is another term to refer to this tense, although I cannot the point of "scholarly grammar has preterite", would you please explain a little bit?

Comment: There are two past tenses: preterite and perfect. The preterite is sometimes called the simple past